# Some times don't want to add image still showing "empty Path name is not legal in c#"

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an Winform Application with SQLite.
I am working with Load Image function into my C# winform Application. At some point user need to add Image and some time user don't need to add images.When form of image load left blank and before saving the form it is showing exception "empty Path name is not legal". Exception occurs on below code

```
byte[] imageBt = null;
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.cnicloc_txt.Text, FileMode.Open,
FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
```

And my Load Image code is as follows

```
private void loadImage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
dlg.Title = "Select CNIC of Owner...";
if(dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
string picPath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
cnicloc_txt.Text = picPath;
}}
```

I am new here please forgive me if I commit any nonsense

Comment: If the user doesn't need to add an image, then simply don't execute that part of the code.  You can also check for an empty path and skip the code (or warn the user).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to test the values before you pass them to constructors. Test the value of this.cnicloc_txt.Text, if null abort the operation. Do something like this:

```
string file = this.cnicloc_txt.Text;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
{
    byte[] imageBt = null;
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cnicloc_txt.Text))
    {
        if (!File.Exists(cnicloc_txt.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The file you entered does not exist.");
            return;
         }

           // load the image....
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's better to write it this way..

```
string file = this.cnicloc_txt.Text.Trim();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
{
    byte[] imageBt = null;
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
}
```